# I read that the average cell will divide between 50-70 times before cell death. How, then, can human cells be constantly dividing?

Tags: human-biology

Aren't those 2 statements contradicting each other?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayflick_limit and e.g. http://book.bionumbers.org/how-quickly-do-different-cells-in-the-body-replace-themselves/.

Take stomach cells. If they divide every 2-9 days, doesn't that mean the stomach cells will all die in about a year (5 days x 70 division)?

Comment: What brings you to the idea that human cells are constantly dividing? And why should this contradict the Hayflick limit?

Comment: Clarified question.

Comment: Has something to do with progenitors I think? I don't exactly know how stomach cells divide, but I would imagine that there is a lining of undifferentiated cells that consistently differentiate towards the inner lining of the stomach. It's differentiated cells that are constricted to the hayflick limit.

Comment: I think your problem might be with a misunderstanding of the meaning of "average".  That doesn't mean that every cell type divides that many times, e.g. neurons seldom if ever divide.

Comment: The answer may simply be yes, as the parent cells are dead, but no since the daughter cells are still alive and kicking.

Comment: You have to consider telomere length, rate of proliferation *and* the presence of stem cells.

Comment: @Bob that makes sense. Can you write the answer? This brings another question: why is hayflick limit associated with ageing if it doesn't apply to stem/progenitor cells and thus body repair?

Comment: @jamesqf I'm not convinced. Average means average - in case of stomach cells, if I randomly pick one stomach cell, on average it will divide in 2-9 days. Some cells (neurons like you mentioned) might be different but most cells do.

Comment: @AliceD Are you saying that if I have a cell that can divide 50 times, after 1 division the daughter cell can still divide 50 times, but the parent can only divide 49 times now? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: YuZhou, I do not think that I know enough about the subject to formulate a proper answer. But, I think doing some research on what I have commented, and on what @CMosychuk has commented, you will be able to find a reasonable answer to both your first question, and your new question. Maybe afterwards you could share your findings in the form of an answer for anyone else who ever asks a similar question?